Dependency from maven does not show up in Plug-in in MANIFEST.MF
I'm in the process of upgrading a large project from Java 17 to Java 21, and I've been changing everything to build via Maven, but now my Eclipse workbench has all kinds of problems. Specifically, there is a very fundamental dependency that is and always was listed in the MANIFEST.MF (org.hibernate.orm.core,bundle-version="5.6.15"), now i want to change it to org.hibernate.orm.core.jakarta version
because i'm migrating from javax to jakarta .
Here my **MANIFEST.MF **file
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Hibernate Core
Bundle-SymbolicName: eu.connective.hibernate.core
Bundle-Version: 8.2.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: eu.connective.hibernate.core.service.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/entityManager.xml,
 OSGI-INF/dataSource.xml
Automatic-Module-Name: eu.connective.hibernate.core
Import-Package: be.lettergen.configuration,
 eu.connective.health.service,
 eu.connective.tenantconfig,
 org.osgi.framework,
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.5.2",
 org.slf4j
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Require-Bundle: jakarta.persistence-api,
 be.lettergen.jdbc.driver,
 org.apache.servicemix.bundles.c3p0,
 org.hibernate.orm.core;bundle-version="5.6.15"
Export-Package: eu.connective.hibernate.core.entity.api.request,
 eu.connective.hibernate.core.entity.counters,
 eu.connective.hibernate.core.service.entitymanager


and here the maven dependency
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

here build.properties
source.. = src/
output.. = target/classes/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               OSGI-INF/


I don't know why plugin be not displayed in Show view.
Please help me.
Thank you.

I tried to Check after installation of plugin whether is it appearing in Running Platform. i did went to Window > Preferences> Plugin Development > Target Platform and i have select Running Platform and checked my plugin.

also i tried to clean the project and reload the target platform



when you say build with maven are you using [tag:tycho]? A plain jar isn't a Eclipse plug-in see Using maven artifacts in PDE / RCP with Tycho

Is this an Eclipse plugin project? If so, you have to specify the dependencies in the MANIFEST.MF and a pom.xml would not be needed for the project at all. Instead, you would have only a parent POM and build your plugin projects with Maven and POM-less Tycho.
